# how to define in svelte.js a global variable over several pages using svelte-router-spa

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to learn svelte and build a card-solution with routing through svelte-router-spa. On each view (index and productdetails) i import my variable basket. This should contain my card-array over the different pages. Unfortunately on every page my array is empty again. How can I define a global var through every page?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code showing how you're importing and setting the variable?

Comment: This sounds like you need a svelte store.

Comment: it delete all the var content on each reload of the page! (I just realized, even on the index page..)

thanks for the hint to svelte store. I just googled it an localStorage could solve my problem, I hope

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a problem that can be solved using a writable store. Stores (if you don't know) are essentially storage for things such as variables and other data which apply across all your components (if imported from your stores file).
The documentation can be found here: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores